# urlretrieve in Python 2.7 doesn't work - error 503 (but in python 3 it does)

Tags: python, urllib

I have a link - http://file.engok.com/englishok/download/ZipMp3100415/auto/20100610/43845-1.mp3
And when I try to retrieve it, in Python 2.7 via urlretrieve (I found out the error name thanks to urllib2.urlopen), it gives me only a few kB file.
Meanwhile in my browser or Python 3 it works.
Python 2.7, doesn't work:

```
urllib.urlretrieve("http://file.engok.com/englishok/download/ZipMp3100415/auto/20100610/43845-1.mp3","file.mp3")
```

Python 3.x works:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://file.engok.com/englishok/download/ZipMp3100415/auto/20100610/43845-1.mp3","file.mp3")
```

However, I want it working in Python 2.x.